# TableView inside Form Sheet not showing properly Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to show a TableView inside a Form Sheet. This is totally working as expected on iPhone. However, when I test it on iPad for some reason the view is bigger than the Form Sheet.
Here is an Image of what I'm talking about:

iPad
[image: iPad Table is bigger than the visible View]

As you can see the text isn't all visible in the frame. Full text is "THIS IS NOT SHOWING FULLY"

Here is what it is supposed to look like (ignore the dark mode)

iPhone
[image: View showing as expected]

In MainController() I presented this page IntroController() by having this in ViewDidLoad()

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: IntroController())
present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In IntroController() this is the code.

```
import UIKit

var tableview: UITableView!

class IntroController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCell.reuseIdentifier()) as! TableCell
        cell.label.text = "Amount"
        cell.typeLabel.text = "THIS IS NOT SHOWING FULLY"
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), style: .grouped)
        view.addSubview(tableview)

        tableview.register(UINib(nibName: TableCell.nibName(), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCell.reuseIdentifier())

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self

    }

}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: show your cell class

Comment: @jawadAli It is not relevant. Look at Sweeper's answer.

Comment: great .. good to know you got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the table view to the `view` of VC as a subview, set it directly as the `view`:

```
view = tableview
```

Alternatively, use a `UITableViewController` directly. I strongly recommend you choose this approach.

```
class IntroController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TableCell.nibName(), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCell.reuseIdentifier())
    }

}
```

I am not sure what causes this, but if I were to guess, it is probably because that `view.frame` is, for some reason, not set to the rect of the content size of VC (yet) when `viewDidLoad` is called. If you move the code that adds the table view as a subview of `view` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, then it works as well:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if view.subviews.count < 1 {
        tableview = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height), style: .grouped)
        tableview.register(UINib(nibName: TableCell.nibName(), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCell.reuseIdentifier())
        view.addSubview(tableview)

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Having it at viewDidLayoutSubviews() as you mentioned fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: @ItsMoShehab Is there a reason why you can't use a `UITableViewController` or setting the table view as the `view`? Those two approaches are much less "fragile".

Comment: The class above was for demonstration only. I didn't set it to UITableViewController as I got an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" next to "let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCell.reuseIdentifier()) as! TableCell". And there is no reason at all why I didn't set the view = tableView other than I'm not sure on how it works like after you set it do you use tableView when registering stuff or modifying it properties or do you just call the view? I didn't want to confuse myself more so I just had them separat

Comment: @ItsMoShehab I'm not sure what caused the unexpectedly found nil error. Are you still using the global `tableview`? You should delete that now. Register the cell on the `tableView` (with a capital `V`) of the table VC. And if you want to use `view = tableView`, just replace the `addSubview` call with that line.

Comment: Yeah I used the global tableView and removed my declaration and got that error. Thats it? Talking about view = tableView. Nice, Im assuming that doing so means that the view is the tableView and any changes to the tableView will automatically change the view. Am I correct?

Comment: @ItsMoShehab yes